# Do candidates with Hispanic/Asian sounding surnames get extra Democratic support in low-information non-partisan state/local US elections?

Tags: united-states, demographics

It is well known that there are partisan differences in different racial groups in the United States. There are also smaller differences in how men and women tend to vote. White Americans favor Republicans as a group, while non-White Americans favor Democrats at higher rates but they're a smaller but increasing percentage of the electorate hence the term minority.

This [effect](https://www.houstonpublicmedia.org/articles/news/politics/texas-elections-2018/2018/03/01/270729/in-texas-republican-judicial-primaries-do-hispanic-sounding-surnames-spell-loss/) has been found with Hispanic Republicans in Texas primaries having a disadvantage. In particular, it talks about an incumbent Republican judge with a Hispanic surname (Alcala) losing to a candidate named Ken Law. The article goes on to quote: "'My bottom line is that Hispanic candidates start out at a slight disadvantage against non-Hispanic candidates because of their name,' said Mike Baselice, a longtime pollster for Republicans in Texas. 'An unfunded or a very low-funded campaign by a Hispanic Republican for either the state Supreme Court or the Court of Criminal Appeals is a tough proposition.'"

I am asking about a hypothesis that there is a reverse effect where Democrats, regardless of the race of the individual Democratic voter, is more likely to support someone with a Hispanic or Asian sounding surname in a *general* election where there is no partisanship indicated on the ballot or at least by widely read news sources. The reason for this is what I wrote in paragraph 1: they would be able to choose a candidate who statistically has a higher *probability* of being a Democrat or Democrat-aligned individual. Such a bias would not exist in a partisan primary election for that reason because every candidate is of the same party.

Notes:

- The reason I am researching this effect on these two groups specifically is that despite backing Democrats more modestly than Black Americans, they have distinct names that many White Americans or even Black Americans don't. For example, the name Li is almost [97% Asian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Li#English), since the name is derived from Mandarin Chinese.
- A bias where female candidates are favored among Democrats or more than Republicans for the same reason absent differences in perceived ethnicity may exist but it isn't the topic of the question.
- I looked up ["heuristics in low-information elections"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=heuristics%20in%20low-information%20elections) and found that it was researched, but many of the articles are old and talk about it in the context of White and Black candidates.
- This is important because many voters don't know or don't care about such elections though many like school board and judicial races have real effects on people's lives. But they may vote in them out of a sense of civic duty especially if they're on the same ballot of a presidential or midterm contest.
- An answer would probably involve looking at the correlation between certain low profile races where the two types of candidates run against each other, and use multiple elections across different states.

Comment: What do you mean by “low-information non-partisan elections”? Specifically, how do I tell if an election is low information or non partisan?

Comment: A non partisan election is one where party affiliation is not on the ballot. Low information tracks closely with non partisan and can be synonymous but not always. Low information means most or at least a significant number of otherwise nationally well informed voters don't know where people running for an office stand. An example could be a judicial election in certain states. The idea is that voters who don't know about candidates (why we say low information) infer their political leanings based on such information, knowing it's not perfect but still better than statistical chance.

Comment: @NumberFile could also maybe correlate with "News deserts", areas with minimal local journalism

Comment: @Ryan_L I believe it does correlate with news deserts. But even in areas with local journalism people are increasingly not reading it.

Comment: Not sure what data could give you an answer (except in rare cases where someone runs with a similar name to a retiring popular incumbent where this happens in judicial races). Few non-partisan races happen in places with a fairly even political split. Disentangling names from ideologies is also intractable at that level.